# Count number of ID in relation and connect to name in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have three tables: films, actors and the relationship actors_film.

I'm trying to decide which actors has been in the most number of movies. If the actor has been in a movie this is shown with `actor_id`(primary key).

I figured I want to count the number of times each `actor_id` shows in the table `film_actor` for each `film_id`, and then connect this with the right name(`actor.first_name`).

I've got the first part down, but can't seem to connect the Count-value to the right name.

```
SELECT actor_id, COUNT(*) AS number_of_films
FROM film_actor 
GROUP by actor_id 
ORDER by 2
DESC limit 1;
```

How would I go forward connecting the actors name from the actor-table?

I'm thinking I need some form of:

```
WHERE actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple inner join between the table `actors` and the table `actors_film`:

```sql
  SELECT a.actor_name, a.actor_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM actors a INNER JOIN actors_films af
      ON a.actor_id = af.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_name, a.actor_id
ORDER BY 3;
```

Comment: This now has the problem that actors with the same name (but different `actor_id`) will be counted as identical. You do need both in the `group by`

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Will try and read more on the chapters about Join. But this was a great help, thanks again!

Comment: Maybe I was too fast. But using your query I get a result that says "Gina" with 35 movies. If I try to add a.last_name it gives me another result, which after manually checking the table seems more correct. How can this be?

My query:


SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.actor_id, COUNT(a.actor_id) AS antal_filmer
    FROM actor a INNER JOIN film_actor af
      ON a.actor_id = af.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
ORDER BY 4
DESC limit 1;